# Error with make command

Tags: software-installation, make, configure

I'm installing [scalpel](https://github.com/sleuthkit/scalpel) and I get the following outputs:

For `./configure`

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for fabs in -lm... yes
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for regcomp in -ltre... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking stddef.h usability... yes
checking stddef.h presence... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking sys/mount.h usability... yes
checking sys/mount.h presence... yes
checking for sys/mount.h... yes
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking sys/timeb.h usability... yes
checking sys/timeb.h presence... yes
checking for sys/timeb.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for mode_t... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for _LARGEFILE_SOURCE value needed for large files... no
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... yes
checking for bzero... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for mkdir... yes
checking for realpath... yes
checking for regcomp... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strncasecmp... yes
checking for strtoul... yes
checking for strtoull... yes
checking for gcj... no
checking for guavac... no
checking for jikes... no
checking for javac... javac
checking if javac works... yes
checking for javac... /usr/bin/javac
checking symlink for /usr/bin/javac... /etc/alternatives/javac
checking symlink for /etc/alternatives/javac... /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating jni/Makefile
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

For `make` I get

```
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/bash /root/scalpel/missing aclocal-1.15 -I m4
 cd . && /bin/bash /root/scalpel/missing automake-1.15 --foreign
configure.ac:7: warning: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE: two- and three-arguments forms are deprecated.  For more info, see:
configure.ac:7: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Modernize-AM_005fINIT_005fAUTOMAKE-invocation
Makefile.am:12: warning: source file 'src/scalpel_exec.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
Makefile.am:12: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
automake-1.15: warning: possible forward-incompatibility.
automake-1.15: At least a source file is in a subdirectory, but the 'subdir-objects'
automake-1.15: automake option hasn't been enabled.  For now, the corresponding output
automake-1.15: object file(s) will be placed in the top-level directory.  However,
automake-1.15: this behaviour will change in future Automake versions: they will
automake-1.15: unconditionally cause object files to be placed in the same subdirectory
automake-1.15: of the corresponding sources.
automake-1.15: You are advised to start using 'subdir-objects' option throughout your
automake-1.15: project, to avoid future incompatibilities.
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/bash /root/scalpel/missing autoconf
/bin/bash ./config.status --recheck
running CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/bash /bin/bash ./configure --no-create --no-recursion
```

and after a lot of good going gives the error here...

```
-DHAVE_STRNCASECMP=1 -DHAVE_STRTOUL=1 -DHAVE_STRTOULL=1 -I. -I../src -Wall -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -g -O2 -MT libscalpel_jni.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libscalpel_jni.Tpo -c libscalpel_jni.cpp -o libscalpel_jni.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libscalpel_jni.Tpo .deps/libscalpel_jni.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O2   -o libscalpel_jni.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libscalpel_jni.lo ../src/libscalpel.la -ltre -lpthread -lm 
libtool: link: g++  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbeginS.o  .libs/libscalpel_jni.o   ../src/.libs/libscalpel.a -ltre -lpthread -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../.. -lstdc++ -lm -lc -lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o  -g -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libscalpel_jni.so.0 -o .libs/libscalpel_jni.so.0.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/.libs/libscalpel.a(scalpel.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
../src/.libs/libscalpel.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:419: recipe for target 'libscalpel_jni.la' failed
make[1]: *** [libscalpel_jni.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/scalpel/jni'
Makefile:524: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I can't figure out the error. As far as I understand this is not due to a missing dependency.

Comment: Please read all the [instructions](https://github.com/sleuthkit/scalpel/blob/master/README).

Comment: Thanks but I did already. Thats where I saw how to compile. I have successfully run `./bootstrap` if thats what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not `automake` package, is the repository

`sudo apt-get install automake`

Installs version `aclocal-1.4`, that's why you can't find `1.5` (In Ubuntu 14,15)

Use this script to install latest
https://github.com/gp187/nginx-builder/blob/master/fix/aclocal.sh